# opponent team or opposing team

Tags: vocabulary

Can we use the word "opponent" as an adjective as in follows?

"Our school beat the oppponent team 2-0."

Should we say "opposing team" or "rival team" in the above-mentioned sentence?

Comment: opposing team but why not just say: the other team?

Comment: Or "we shutout our opponents 2-0" works.

Comment: @Lambie Doesn't the word _other_ sound weird in this context? I mean other team can be any team in general.

Comment: @DhanishthaGhosh: no. _**The** other_ is specific, so in context would almost always be taken to mean "the other team in the particular competition".

Comment: Oh. I get it. Thanks @ColinFine

Answer (score 1):

- opposing is the adjective
- opponent is the noun

So: opposing team or opponents

Answer (score 0):

Using "opposing team" would be correct in this context, but if you want to focus on one specific opponent and their team, you could also say "opponent's team".